# 3d scatter plot remains empty in R plotly

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

I have a simple question regarding a 3d scatter plot using the plotly package in R. It appears all of the plots are working with the exception of the 3d scatter and line plots. To test this I've tried the following code (= taken from the cheat sheet):

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", x = c(9,8,5,1), y = c(1,2,4,8),z = c(11,8,15,3),
        mode = "markers")
```

[image]

I ended up with a plot containing only the axis and not the actual points. To troubleshoot I've added colors which got me confused as the legend with the color scale did appear but not the points themselves. I did notice the axis have the wrong scale ((80,-80),(60,-60),(100,-100)).

Furthermore, the 3d surface plot en 2d scatter plot examples worked perfectly.

Comment: could you please include the graph that you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I reverted to the older package (4.5.6 was found to be working), please find the script below:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("plotly", version = "4.5.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Works for me. I reverted from 4.6.0 to 4.5.6. In doing so, was required to also install tibble, tidyr, and jsonlite. Now a basic scatter3d works.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking forward? 
[image]

```
> plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", x = c(9,8,5,1), y = c(1,2,4,8),z = c(11,8,15,3),
+         mode = "markers")
```

There is no error with your code, clear your R-consel and try again and check the version of the library as well.

Comment: What version of plotly are you using? I get the same behavior as OP.

Comment: Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm using plotly version 4.6.0 and tried rebooting the entire computer just to be sure (no effect).

Comment: @Viktor 4.6.0 for me, too.

Comment: Note: reinstalling package has no effect